# Blender Necklace Neck Rotation Deformation in Rigid Part

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am creating some props for a character I made.. I made a peace necklace that is moving with the rig and fully weighted to the neck bone.. So only one bone carries weights..

The strap moves correctly, the sign is deforming like on the picture.. The hippie iron part should be round & is deforming a bit from circle into an oval.. Anything I can do to prevent the sign from deforming?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: without seeing any settings you made - we can just guess around. So pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: Give it uniform weights and it won't deform.  To give it uniform weights, select all verts in it, actively select one vertex, and hit the "copy" button on toolbar/item/vertex weights.

Comment: My approach was too simple.. :-).. The 'right' way to do it apparently is through simulation.. Don't know if the complexity is worth it for me yet.. Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjVhS0TyyX8

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers..

Nathan, I used solution as you suggested. But there was only one vertex bone group with weights, which is on the neck. So this was not the issue..

Chris, next time I will provide a Blend File..

Issue was in surface deform modifier I used.. This caused the necklace to deform other than bone deformation..